# SNMP4J Client gives "Unsupported security level"

Tags: java, docker, snmp, snmp4j, snmpd

I'm about to implement a Client/Agent setup in order to learn using 
SNMP. I want to establish a secure and encrypted communication using SNMPv3 and `authPriv` as security level.
Here's my setup:

**Agent**
The Agent is running on Ubuntu (within a Docker image). To set it up, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.incredigeek.com/home/setup-snmp-v3-on-debian-or-ubuntu/).
My `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` looks like this:

```
agentAddress udp:161
...
createUser authOnlyUser MD5 "test1234"
createUser authPrivUser SHA "test1234" DES
createUser internalUser MD5 "test1234"
...
rouser authOnlyUser
rwuser authPrivUser authPriv
```

SNMP is running on port `161`, which is forwarded to port `1025` by Docker.

**Client**
I could ensure that my Agent is working properly using

1. `snmpget` on the same machine (Ubuntu, within Docker):
   `snmpget -v3 -a SHA -A test1234 -X test1234 -l authPriv -u authPrivUser localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`
2. `snmpget` from a remote machine (Debian):
   `snmpget -v3 -u authPrivUser -X test1234 -A test1234 -l authPriv -x DES -a SHA <HOST-IP>:1025 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0`
3. Using [SNMP-Tester](https://www.paessler.com/tools/snmptester).

In all three cases I get the expected value for the given OID:
`Linux 9b98a8808b1a 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64`.

Now I wanted to implement a Client with Java, using the [latest version 3.2.2 of snmp4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.snmp4j/snmp4j/3.2.2). This is what I have implemented:

```java
public class SNMPTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // enable logging
        ConsoleLogFactory consoleLogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory();
        consoleLogFactory.getRootLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.DEBUG);
        LogFactory.setLogFactory(consoleLogFactory);

        TransportMapping<? extends Address> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

        // create and add user security model
        OctetString localEngineId = new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID());
        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(), localEngineId, 0);
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

        // user credentials
        OctetString securityName = new OctetString("authPrivUser");
        OctetString authPassphrase = new OctetString("test1234");
        OctetString privPassphrase = new OctetString("test1234");
        OID authProtocol = AuthSHA.ID;
        OID privProtocol = PrivDES.ID;

        UsmUser usmUser = new UsmUser(securityName, authProtocol, authPassphrase, privProtocol, privPassphrase);
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(securityName, usmUser);

        // create target
        UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
        target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
        target.setSecurityName(securityName);
        target.setAddress(GenericAddress.parse("udp:127.0.0.1/1025"));
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
        target.setRetries(3);
        target.setTimeout(10000);

        transport.listen();

        ScopedPDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0")));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
        ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, target);
        if (event != null) {
            System.out.println(event.getUserObject());
            System.out.println(event.getError());
            System.out.println(event.getPeerAddress());
            PDU responsePDU = event.getResponse();
            System.out.println(responsePDU.getErrorStatus());
            System.out.println(responsePDU.getErrorIndex());
            if (responsePDU.getErrorStatus() == PDU.noError) {
                for (int k = 0; k < responsePDU.size(); k++) {
                    VariableBinding vb = responsePDU.get(k);
                    if (vb != null) {
                        System.out.println(vb.getOid() + "-" + vb.getVariable().toString());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("SNMP Error:" + responsePDU.getErrorStatusText());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("SNMP send unsuccessful.");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using the same credentials and protocols like mentioned above. But when I run it I receive the following Exception:
`org.snmp4j.MessageException: Message processing model 3 returned error: Unsupported security level`

What am I doing wrong here? As the user `authPrivUser` is configured to use the `authPriv` security level on the Agent's side and I'm also setting the level to `AUTH_PRIV` within the client and pass the correct credentials, I don't know why this exception is thrown.

Thanks in advance for any support and hints!

**EDIT**
I figured out that the code I posted above *does* work using SNMP4J v2.7.0. Any version >=3.0.0 throws error `Unsupported security level`. Unfortunately, using an old version from Nov. 2018 cannot be the solution...

Answer (score 4):

In SNMP4J 3.x the security protocol `AuthSHA` (and `AuthMD5`) are no longer added by default to the static `SecurityProtocols` instance because they are now considered as unsafe.

You can add it again by calling:

```
SecurityProtocols.addAuthenticationProtocol(new AuthSHA());
```